# Error no module named curses

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, telnet, curses

When I try to run the following code...

```
from telnetsrvlib import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
"Testing - Accept a single connection"
class TNS(SocketServer.TCPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True

class TNH(TelnetHandler):
    def cmdECHO(self, params):
        """ [<arg> ...]
        Echo parameters
        Echo command line parameters back to user, one per line.
        """
        self.writeline("Parameters:")
        for item in params:
            self.writeline("\t%s" % item)
    def cmdTIME(self, params):
        """
        Print Time
        Added by dilbert
        """
        self.writeline(time.ctime())

logging.getLogger('').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

tns = TNS(("0.0.0.0", 8023), TNH)
tns.serve_forever()
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\telserv.py", line 1, in <module>
from telnetsrvlib import *
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\telnetsrvlib-1.0.2-py2.4.egg\telnetsrvlib.py", line 31, in <module>
import curses.ascii
  File "C:\Python27\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
from _curses import *
```

I am running python 2.7 and have imported the telnetsrvlib library and I am running the code on windows 7. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: install curses (I think in windows its ncurses) your telnetserver library may not be compatible with windows http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_MNiXCPQAY

Comment: If memory serves, this is also the error you'll see if you have a circular import.  If A imports B imports C imports B, B will be unavailable but also unloadable when C attempts to import it, so you'll get an error.

Comment: ***you can even find the source code and paste it into the lib folder!***
*After that, importing will go on as usual.* <!-- begin snippet: js hide: true console: true babel: false --> <!-- language: lang-html --> <h1>Maker's Effect</h1> <input type = 'text' value = 'Enter Anything to Test your Keyboard : '/> <input type = 'button' value = ' Done! '/> <!-- end snippet -->

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Install the UniCurses module from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/UniCurses

You may need to alter some of your code in order to use it, as it provides the functionality of NCurses, not the vanilla curses library.

Unfortunately, no direct Python for Windows port of curses exists.

Comment: Thanks it was an issue with the default curses module

Comment: Is there any doc for Unicurses? This was about all Google came up with: https://github.com/Chiel92/unicurses

Answer (score 16):

You could also look into installing the curses module from here:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses.

It allows python's native curses to be used on Windows, so all your standard python curses code can be used.

Answer (score 14):

That works for me:

```
pip install windows-curses
```

Answer (score 5):

inspired by @YKB, I did this for Ubuntu 16.04 and Python3.5.2,

`sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev`,

and then go to source code of Python, and `make`, two new files are created.

```
_curses.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
_curses_panel.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

And then copy them to `lib-dynload` folder at where you installed your python.

Answer (score 4):

Got the same error with Python 3.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 and here is how I fixed it.

My `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/` directory did not have the following files -

```
_curses.cpython-34m.so
_curses_panel.cpython-34m.so
```

Got a copy of the latest Python 3.4.2 [source](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/).
Then (extracted &) compiled it:

```
./configure
make
```

Now the `.so` files I need were in `build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/` and I copied them to `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/`.