# Where is curses in python 3.9.5?

Tags: python

I just updated from 3.6 and curses is nowhere to be found in pip list. When I try to run my program I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/HD/Documents/Python/program/menu.py", line 1, in <module>
    import curses
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/curses/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from _curses import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'
```

"pip3 install curses" gives me

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement curses (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for curses
```

Any ideas? Does python not come with curses anymore?

Edit: This is in Ubuntu

Comment: Are you on a windows machine?

Comment: This is on linux

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is called unicurses, but I could be wrong as I'm not a linux user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error no module named curses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410116/error-no-module-named-curses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using an earlier version of python (3.6.9)

Sadly, this is probably the only solution.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by using below command. It adds support for the standard Python curses module on Windows.
Read more about it [here.](https://pypi.org/project/windows-curses/)

> pip install windows-curses

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, you need to install [UniCurses](https://pypi.org/project/UniCurses/) which is OS-independent. Note that `UniCurses` hasn't need maintained in a while, but you could find some more information on it [here](https://github.com/unicurses/unicurses).

Comment: It doesn't install. "Fatal error: this Python release does not support ctypes, please upgrade your Python distribution if you want to use UniCurses on a linux platform." But I'm using 3.9.5 the most recent version of python.

Comment: Given how old UniCurses is, there's a good chance it's not compatible with the most recent version of Python.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/Uni-Curses/ https://github.com/unicurses/unicurses#installing-unicurses